# Re-order Documents across several Lucene Indexes

Tags: indexing, lucene.net, lucene

My scenario is that I have x (x generally being greater than 1k) number of Lucene Indexes. They contain documents in a random order, one Index could have the oldest and youngest item.

I wish to recreate the Indexes so that they will now contain the Documents in date order (there is a field, date). This is required so that my search engine is smarter when it goes to query Indexes based on a date range (I no longer will have to load all Indexes).

I could do this based on some date query and get a bunch of Documents but when I retrieve a Document it will be missing the non stored fields. It means I can no longer add this Document to a new Index (without going back and fetching the orig item and extracting again).

Is there something clever I can do? I was thinking to somehow create a new Index with X number of Documents with just one unique field and try merge Indexes so that the non stored fields remain intact.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: There is a way to merge indexes without having stored fields. I just can't tell you how. e.g. Katta does this: http://katta.sourceforge.net/documentation/how-to-merge-indexes

Comment: I think Merging indexes is not too much of an issue. I could easily add one Index to another by calling .AddIndexes on the IndexWriter.